# add access control allow origin in nginx discourse.conf

Tags: ajax, nginx, cors, discourse

So i have an application on `forums.awake-gaming.com` and have a page on `awake-gaming.com`  which `POST` a form to `forums.awake-gaming.com` via ajax .

As Expected i get an

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://forums.awake-gaming.com/posts. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://awake-gaming.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, as i have access to the server, i added this in the `discourse.conf` file under `nginx/conf.d` directory.

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "http://awake-gaming.com/join-us.html";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With";
```

I restarted nginx and tried to submit the form again, In Theory, this should work but i still get the same error in console :

And the ajax call didn't return success either. but weird enough, the data is posted to the `forums.awake-gaming.com` and it is posted(via discourse api).

So were i went wrong?, i tried to ask at meta.discourse.org but they said that it is some problem with nginx and not with discourse. Is adding the header in `.conf` file is enough ? or i need to do something with rails as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify just "`http://awake-gaming.com`", not "`http://awake-gaming.com/join-us.html`" for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value, as the error message says. Actually, if you're using Chrome, it will tell something like "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' whitelists only '`http://awake-gaming.com/join-us.html`'. Origin '`http://awake-gaming.com`' is not in the list, and is therefore not allowed access."

On a side note, there are extra colons after `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, you better remove them, but I don't think they're the culprit here.